# How to construct drag and droppable flow chart using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have created flow chart builder using jquery UI and connection using JSPlumb community edition. Now, I trying to rewrite flowchart builder with Vue.js. I need a library for flow chart with drag and drop to integrate with Vue.js.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for something similar now. Have you found any good open-source libraries? I have posted my question here, can you please have look and provide some suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69885058/7584240